# How to: On click open new page in new tab and redirect the old one

Tags: javascript, html

Been trying to find some solution but I wasn't able to. I need to get a button to fire two events on one click. This code worked for firefox but it doesn't on Chrome:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>EXAMPLE</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeLocation (){
  window.location = "https://www.bing.com";
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <input type="text">
  <button onclick="changeLocation()">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to redirect users to a new page in new tab and redirect the main page (old one) after the button has been clicked.
Is there any solution which would also work on Chrome?

Would really appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function changeLocation() {
document.getElementById("form").submit();
window.open("https://www.bing.com","_blank");
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="https://www.google.com">
<input type="text">
<button onclick="changeLocation()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will help you. By the way you need to use the name attribute in the input tag to submit the data.